# Tests in a maven project do not run with Netbeans but run fine with Eclipse. maven-surefire-plugin

Tags: eclipse, maven, netbeans, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

so essentially I have a big maven project. When I open it in netbeans, strangely if I add any new junit test class or even if I rename existing test classes I cannot run any of them using "Test File", but old test classes run fine. I receive a message:
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.14.1:test (default-cli) on project sga: No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.) -> [Help 1]

Strangely, if I open the same project with Eclipse, all new and renamed classes run fine without errors with "Run As JUnit".

Could help me to make the new tests run in netbeans? Thank you

Comment: Show your pom file? How are your Test classes named? Where are they located? Does the build work on command line?

Comment: Thank you very much for your hints. That was the problem with the naming. All test classes names should end with Test. Still I do not understand, and would appreciate if someone could explain, why in Eclipse test classes do not have to have an ending Test?

Comment: Eclipse used to parse sources to check if it is a JUnit test (with some mistakes). NetBeans uses naming convention (which causes other problems).